# Either PHP convert JSON values to have keys or PostgreSQL assign values to keys

Tags: php, json, postgresql

I simply need to store text (rows have their own separate date).

Either...

**1.** How do I read (either of) the following value(s) in to a PHP array that I can iterate over via a `foreach` loop?

...*or*...

**2.** how do I `INSERT INTO` a table a value assigned to a key (which is *not* clarified at all in the PostgreSQL documentation)?

```
{".022 x 2.031"}
{".012 x 3.621"}
```

So I currently have single measurement values (to be treated as text purely for records) formatted as the first format above. I try to convert the row data in PHP and get `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` for the following:

```
$array = json_decode($row1['material_size']);

foreach ($array as $k1) {echo $k1;}
```

Comment: If you could restructure that as something that's actually JSON that would be better. `"x"`, `["x"]` and `{"string":"x"}` are all valid. `{"x"}` is not.

Comment: @tadman Yes, but how do I tell PostgreSQL to assign values to a key?

Comment: You supply the JSON value as text, inserting into it as you would a string field. What's the problem here?

Comment: You should start by providing proper information. Postgres version, table definition, desired result. I am not sure I understand the question so far.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Updated. I have another column that stores `integer[]` and have used this approach without any problem.

Comment: My apologies, this is only the second time I've worked with arrays in PostgreSQL; the key was wrapping the row in `array_to_json()` within the query and *then* PHP can handle it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after doing even more searching and reading I decided to see if I could just convert the data via PostgreSQL directly:

```
SELECT array_to_json(material_size) AS material_size FROM table;
```

Now I get the array data correctly...

```
$array = json_decode($row1['material_size']);
print_r($array);

Array
(
    [0] => .022 x 2.031
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, dimension is a structured data. If your data is 2 dimensional, you may use the `point` datatype or create your own [composite type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/rowtypes.html). I'd suggest to use [Pomm](http://www.pomm-project.org) to get it converted to a PHP array.

If you want to stick with Json then you can select on keys [like stated in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html) but you need to overwrite the complete JSON value every time you want to update a value.